# Is possible to train Tensorflow to detect defects on an object?

Tags: tensorflow

i have to say i'm totally newbie on Tensorflow. I need to train a model that using photos of the same object detect if some of them has imperfections, scratchs and so on,  not detecting what object it is. Is this possible using Tensorflow? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer myself, the idea is to train a model that recognizes the defects in an image, not the object with the defect.

Comment: Can you please write the steps in detail. how you did this.

Comment: I don't have acomplish nothing yet, sorry.